# How to access a client connected to a different router from my router when both the routers are connected

Tags: router, ip, lan, dhcp

let me explain my situation in detail.

I have a modem that connects to the internet with LAN IP: 192.168.1.1
The modem further connects to a wifi and wired router-1 which is assigned a dynamic IP by the Modem. The router further has its LAN IP: 192.168.0.1 and all the clients connect to it with IP: 192.168.0.x. It has DHCP enabled from 192.168.1.21-250. All mobiles, laptops use these. This router-1 is also connected to a station PC with IP: 192.168.0.5.

Next, this router-1 has a LAN cable running around 50 meters where it connects to a router-2 WAN port which has the same SSID as of router-1 but different channel. Router-2 further has its WAN IP: 192.168.0.2, whereas LAN IP: 192.168.2.1. So when i take my laptop from the wifi range of router-1 to router-2, it easily switches between channels and everything is fine.

The problem is: when my lappy is using the network of router-2, it gets an IP: 192.168.2.x through DHCP, However, at that point of time, it cant access the files in client station PC with IP: 192.168.0.5. How do i solve this.

PS: All the routers are of TP-Link

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to accomplish your goal. Would be to assign the following netmask to both your DHCP pools: `255.255.252.0` ( `/22` in [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation ).
Tho you should be advised that the gateways (and hence reserved IPs) will initially change. But in the end it should all work for you.